# How can I query my data by published date (newest first) using Apollo and Graphql?

Tags: sorting, graphql, apollo-server

I have React page that is fetching data via Graphql.
I'm using Strapi as backend and queries are already generated.
I´m querying my data in the frontend like this

```
query GetData{
  datas(limit:3){
    id
    published_at
  }
}
```

In the documentation I found this example about how to sort my queries by some especific order

```
GET /users?_sort=email:ASC,dateField:DESC
```

but is not really clear how to use it with the query structure.
I tried something like this and other variations

```
query GetPodcasts{
  podcasts?_sort=published_at:DESC(limit:3){
    id
    published_at
  }
}
```

but it didn't work.

I may need some help understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphql is like an Rest Api but with one end point to the server ,
this query with name GetData , point to datas query but you should define this query in the backend.
please watch some tutorials that will guide you step by step.
you can learn more about graphql here
https://graphql.org/learn/

try this:

```
query GetData{
  datas(input:{
    sort:{id:"asc"},
    data:{limit:3}
    }){
    id
    published_at
  }
}
```

for more info
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/graphql.html#query-api

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering... Maybe I should add to my description that I'm using Strapi as backend and queries are already generated, I just want to know how to order my data by date (newest first) in the frontend

Comment: edited the answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

In a forum some nice people also gave me an answer.
When using graphql in frontend and want to sort or filter the data, just have to use "" to specify the sort or filter.
In my case it just had to be:

```
query GetData{
  datas(limit:3, sort:"published_at:desc"){
    id
    published_at
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, published_at:desc shoud be as follow, 
publishedAt:desc

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me in Strapi v4:

```
sort: "publishedAt:DESC"
```

...

```
query GetVideos($page: Int!, $pageSize: Int!) {
    videos(
      pagination: { page: $page, pageSize: $pageSize }
      sort: "publishedAt:DESC"
    ) {
      __typename
      data {
        __typename
        id
        attributes {
          __typename
          createdAt
          publishedAt              
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```